# Passing function to child component

Tags: reactjs

I'm passing a child component a function of `highlight()` via props but I'm having issues running that function on the child component. When I log `this.props` to the console in `componentDidMount()` I see it, but when I try to call it it doesn't work.

```
class Queen extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('1) The Queen component has mounted!');
    this.props.highlight()
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>
          {this.props.name}
        </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class King extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      highlighted: false
    }
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('2) The King component has mounted!');
  }


   highlight() {
    this.setState({
      highlighted: !this.state.highlighted
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <h1>The King's Queen is...</h1>
        <Queen 
          name="Amelia" 
          highlight={() => this.highlight.bind(this)}
          className={this.state.highlighted ? 'highlight' : ''}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<King />, 
                document.querySelector(".wrapper"));
```

Is this happening because the Queen component has mounted before the King as it's a child component? Trying to wrap my head around what's happening here and just as importantly why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the handler instead of just binding it.

```
<Queen 
  name="Amelia" 
  highlight={this.highlight.bind(this)}
  className={this.state.highlighted ? 'highlight' : ''}
/>
```

Going even further, you can bind your handler in the constructor

```
class King extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.highlight = this.highlight.bind(this)
   }

   highlight() {
    ...
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <h1>The King's Queen is...</h1>
        <Queen 
          name="Amelia" 
          highlight={this.highlight}
          className={this.state.highlighted ? 'highlight' : ''}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Aha yes. Cheers!